# $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{x}{n}(1+\frac{x}{n})^{n-1} = ?$

Tags: calculus, limits

I do not understand why this expression simplifies to

$$xe^x$$

My intuition tells me

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{x}{n}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right) ^{n-1} & = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{x}{n+x}\left(1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^{n} \\
\end{align}$$

where the right half of the expression goes to $e^x$ but I do not see why the left half is $x$.

May I have some help, please?

Comment: Are you sure it is supposed to be $\frac{x}{n}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n-1}$ rather than just $x\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n-1}$? The former goes to $0$, while the latter goes to $xe^{x}$.

Comment: You were totally right.  It was my mistake. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The limit is $0$, not $xe^{x}$.